# How do I call a python 3 cgi script on RedHat Enterprise Linux using their Software Collections?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

I'm trying to run Python 3 CGI script on a RedHat Enterprise Linux System.

Python 3 is installed as part of their Software Collections Library.

Normally I would use #!/usr/bin/python3 at the start of the file, but I'm not sure what to put to get to the python 3 binary in the SCL.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I gave up on using python 3 in the SCL and installed python 3 from source. The issue is that to start python 3 from the SCL you have execute either the command 'scl enable python33 python' or  'source /opt/rh/python33/enable' neither which I believe you can do from a '#! /usr/bin/env' in a CGI script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical answer for such cases is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

That allows your environment's `$PATH` to determine where `python` really is.